# Get hash of the latest deployed commit in Heroku

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

How to actually get hash of the latest commit deployed to Heroku in 2022?

---

Yes, this is a duplicate of a lot of other SO questions. But neither of them worked for me.

1. **[Access current git commit number from within Heroku app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217645/access-current-git-commit-number-from-within-heroku-app)**

   - `SOURCE_VERSION` property does not exist on `process.env` (not even `undefined`);
   - logging the whole `process.env` object, I couldn't find any environment variable that would contain anything remotely relevant;
   - `/etc/heroku/dyno` file does not exist on runtime;
2. **[Heroku - Display hash of current commit in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583282/heroku-display-hash-of-current-commit-in-browser)**

   - `heroku config` doesn't show anything relevant;
   - `heroku labs:enable runtime-dyno-metadata` – Heroku Labs is [not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37570681/enable-heroku-labs-feature-in-heroku-review-apps) for Heroku Review Apps, which I am a heavy user of;
   - [`post-commit` hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14924922/4554883) seems too hacky, I'm considering this approach as a last resort;

Similar to using `post-commit` hook, I could use available values of `process.env.npm_package_repository_url`, and `process.env.HEROKU_PR_NUMBER` to fetch the latest commit hash through an HTTP call. Similarly, I'm considering this approach as a last resort.

Comment: How did you deploy your app? Are you using `git push`, GitHub integration, Docker...?

Comment: I'm using integration with GitHub